# Fundamental period of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

The fundamental period of the function $\sin(\frac{\pi[x]}{12})+\tan(\frac{\pi[x]}{3})+\cos(\frac{\pi x}{4})$ is

(A) 12

(B) 24

(C) 36

(D) function is non-periodic

(where $[\cdot]$ represents the greatest integer function)

My approach is as follows:
With $N$ an integer,

$[x+N]=[x]+N$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: What does $[x]$ mean? The "round down to the nearest integer" ( "floor" function, $\lfloor x\rfloor$)? Or something else?

Comment: Hint: what period does each term have? They're all integers; what's their LCM?